# SSIS Condition that include two connections/data bases

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

In a SSIS package , I need some sort of condition that include two connections.

The simplified problem is:
A simple CSV import to SQL Server, DB1, table 1( col1, col2 ). 
I need to populate table 1 > col2 = '1'   if col1     is found in    another database , DB2 > table 2 ;      db2 is specified as a different connection in package.

and table 1 > col2 = '2'   if col1 is not found in the lookup database.

any guidance is appreciated,
ta

Comment: To restate, you need to populate a column based on whether a reference record was found? If exists, then 1, else 2

Comment: yes, that is the point, just that the reffernce column is located in another db, reffernced by a connection other than the connection I need to do the update.

Comment: The lookup function should do exactly what you need if I'm parsing your question correctly.

Comment: yes, it did exactly what I needed in terms of results; in terms of performance it is a little bit exaustive, I think, I find it exaustive to lookup after every record in the data set, but it works. ta

Answer (score 0):

Put the CSV import in one data flow, then in a dependent data flow use an OLE DB Source that contains the results you need as the output of a SQL query. 
Feed that into an OLEDB destination.

Your query would look similar to:

```
SELECT t1.col1, 
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT null FROM db2.dbo.table2 t2 WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1) THEN '2'
ELSE '1' END as [col2]
FROM db1.dbo.table1 t1
```

Comment: thank you, I was not sure how to use both db1 and db2, in the same query, to which two databases I reffer with two separate connections; I managed to resolve it using a Lookup Transformation.